# mysql UUID_SHORT() for older versions of mysql

Tags: mysql, function

I was just wondering if anyone could help me create a mysql function `UUID_SHORT()` for mysql, as the version I'm using doesn't have that function.

From what I saw, the function essentially calls

```
(server_id & 255) << 56
+ (server_startup_time_in_seconds << 24)
+ incremented_variable++;
```

But I have no idea how to make that into a function that I could use.

So again, all I'm looking for is some help recreating the function for use in an older version of mysql, I don't/can't upgrade, and don't care about auto-incremented fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math part should be fairly straightforward.  As for the counter, I guess the only way to implement that would be using a tiny table holding one value that you increment each time.  Tip: Make sure to lock the table in your function before reading it, and unlock after writing.